# Prevent knockout binding to update target property of complex object immediately

Tags: knockout.js

I've asked this question the other day,

[Knockout same form for edit and create items of an observable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265991/knockout-same-form-for-edit-and-create-items-of-an-observable-array)

Now I would like to change slightly the behaviour.

As you could see in the fiddle lagerone did http://jsfiddle.net/danne567/gTHpu/31/ the moment you focus out of the input text the target is updated. I would like to delay this until you click the update button.

I've done some workaround and seems to work, but I'm not happy with it:

I don't make the inner properties of the address observables, I've added an order to the Address object and sorted the array by it. Then whenever you edit the address and click update I remove it from the observable array and added again (with the changed fields) and sort again the array.

```
self.updateAddress = function() {
    self.AddressEditingMode(false);
    self.addresses.remove(this);
    self.addresses.push(new Address(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.formAddress),self.EditingAddressOrder()));
    self.addresses(_.sortBy(self.addresses(), function(address) { return address.Order; }));
    self.emptyAddressForm();
};
```

I understand it's difficult to put in context with my explanation so feel free to point me whatever you would need.

Thanks,

Marco

Ps. _.sortBy is for the underscore function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most of the way there, but what you want to do is work off of a new copy of your address, and then only apply the changes on update.  I modified your Address view model to be a little easier to work with in regards to updates:

Address View Model:

```
function Address(address) {
    var self = this;
    self.Line1 = ko.observable();

    // we'll use this method to update existing addresses that have been modified
    self.initialize = function (data) {
        self.Line1(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Line1));
    }

    self.initialize(address);
}
```

Key changes in main VM:

```
    // this will store the currently selected address from the observableArray
    var selectedAddress;
    // added this just as example, use it to toggle which buttons to show (see fiddle)
    self.isEditing = ko.observable(false);

    // helper function to clear out the input if the user doesnt want to 
    //  update the address or is finished with it
    function clearSelected() {
        self.isEditing(false);
        self.newAddress(new Address(""));
    }

    self.editAddress = function (addressItem) {
        // set the address item that was picked to selectedAddress variable
        selectedAddress = addressItem;
        // set what mode we're in
        self.isEditing(true);
        // create new copy of address to work off of based on the clicked address item
        self.newAddress(new Address(addressItem));
    };

    // once update is clicked, the copy of the context is passed to this function
    self.updateAddress = function (address) {
        // call the new initialize function on the address 
        //  view model that we've saved as a reference in the 
        //  original list with whatever values have changed
        selectedAddress.initialize(address);
        // clear the selected item and reset the mode so we can add new items
        clearSelected();
    };
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/58mU5/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to correct your code, browse it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gTHpu/32/

First of all, I change the Address constructor (add id param)

```
var id = 1;
function Address(address) {
    this.id = id++;
    this.Line1 = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(address.Line1));
}
```

Then, I simlified new address var:

```
self.addresses = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(addresses, function(address) {
    return address.id ? address : new Address(address);
}));
self.newAddress = ko.observable('');
self.addAddress = function() {
    self.addresses.push(new Address({Line1: this.newAddress()}));
    self.newAddress('');
};
```

Then, add remove function

```
self.removeAddress = function (address) {
    self.addresses.remove(address);
}
```

I change the update address process:

```
self.addressToEdit = null;
self.editAddress = function(addressItem) {
    self.addressToEdit = addressItem;
    self.newAddress(addressItem.Line1());
};

self.updateAddress = function () {
    if (self.addressToEdit) {
        self.addressToEdit.Line1(self.newAddress());
        self.addressToEdit = null;
    }
    self.newAddress('');
};
```

Is that solution will works for you?

PS. Sorry for my english, feel free to correct me, because I'm a non-native speaker :)

Comment: The code need to refactor, but I can't do this, because I don't know, how you use that code in your project

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, it works perfectly fine and therefore I upvoted it, but I eventually opted for Kevin's solution as I liked the idea of the self containing Address object.